# WCF service call failed with web error 400 Bad Request from Android Web App (Phone Gap)

Tags: android, wcf

I am new to the android and web app technology, what i have is HTML5 pages and java-scripts from which i created the android native web app using Phone Gap. I have deployed the web app on my android device.
Now, when i try to access through my web app I am getting service call failed erro
"Service call failed. 400 Bad Request".
What i understood here is my WCF service is running on a different server and my web pages are at my local device.
So, is there a configuration that i need to do with the service or in Phone Gap

I would appreciate the help given !!!